# Is there some seed for choice from np.random distributions?

Tags: python, stochastic-process

I want to model wiener process and I want to add some implementation of elementary result, so I want to write something like this:

```py
# w is elementary result
def W(T, w = 0, dt = 0.001):
    x = [0]
    for t in np.arange(0, T, dt):
        x.append(x[-1] + np.random.normal(0,dt, w))
    return x
```

and I expect that with same `w` I got same output of `W`. But `np.random.normal` doesn't support such thing. How can I implement it?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html?highlight=seed#numpy.random.seed You can set your seed here.

Comment: that doesn't work, I am still getting different arrays

Answer (score 0):

Maybe clarity on how set seed works.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
np.random.normal(0,0.001,1)
>> array([0.00176405]) #My output
np.random.normal(0,0.001,1)
>>array([0.00040016])

np.random.seed(0)
np.random.normal(0,0.001,1)
>> array([0.00176405]) #Same output
np.random.normal(0,0.001,1)
>>array([0.00040016])
```

Every time you want the same results, you have to reset the seed again.